# React error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a navigation menu with React, but am getting this error.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Header`.
```

This is my header.js. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I do have a roster.js file and export it using "const Roster = () => { return etc... then export default Roster."

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from "styled-components"
import logo_image from "../../static/logo_white_trans.png"
import title_image from "../../static/title.png"

import { Roster } from "./roster"
import { Home } from "./index"

//Removed CSS styling

const Header = () => {
    const [nav, showNav] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div id='header' style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black', display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '20% 60% 20%' }}>
            <div id='logo' style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                <img alt='logo' src={logo_image} style={{ maxHeight: '15vh', maxWidth: '100%', width: 'auto !important' }} />
            </div>
            <div id='title' style={{ position: 'relative', margin: '0 auto', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <img alt='title' src={title_image} style={{ maxHeight: '15vh', maxWidth: '100%', width: 'auto !important' }} />
            </div>
            <div id='menu' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <MenuIcon nav={nav} onClick={() => showNav(!nav)}>
                    <div />
                    <div />
                    <div />
                </MenuIcon>
                <Menuas nav={nav}>
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <Route path="/" component={Home}>Home</Route>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <Route path="/roster" component={Roster}>Roster</Route>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </Menuas>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Header
```

Then my roster.js file looks like this, so I think it's exporting correctly?

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"

const profile_style = {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    height: '25%',
    width: '80vw',
    scrollSnapAlign: 'center'
}
const Roster = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <Header style={{ alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
            </Header >
            <div style={{ height: "75vh", width: "90vw", display: "flex", overflowX: "scroll", scrollSnapType: "x mandatory", margin: "0 auto", gap: '5vh' }}>
                <div id="1" style={profile_style}>
                </div>
                <div id="2" style={profile_style}>
                </div>
                <div id="3" style={profile_style}>
                </div>
                <div id="4" style={profile_style}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <Footer style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            </Footer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Roster
```